# Looping through an array in Excel VBA

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, for-loop

I am trying to get familiar with arrays in VBA. I Want to copy lines that contain "1" in another sheet and place them at the end of the list and then delete then from the original sheet. Here is the code I put together. It does not work.

Can anybody help me please?

```
Sub array1()
Dim Oblast() As Variant
Dim dimension1 As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim dvojPole() As Variant

Worksheets("live_position").Activate

Oblast = Range("A2", Range("A1").End(xlDown))
dimension1 = UBound(Oblast, 1)
ReDim dvojPole(1 To dimension1, 1 To 2)

For i = 1 To dimension1
Set dest = Worksheets("closed").Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0)
    If dvojPole(i, 1) = 1 Then
        dvojPole(i, 1).EntireRow.Copy Destination:=dest
        dvojPole(i, 1).EntireRow.Delete
    End If

Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: does not work means....

Comment: Have you tried the code?

Comment: @Ludek "It does not work: is not a sufficient problem description.  _You_ need to explain what you want your code to do, what it currently does and where you are stuck trying to fix it.

Comment: @Chris Neilsen. Well, I have indicated already what the problem was when I made the first post. I will try to make it clearer. So this code supposed to copy all lines with value "1" in column "A" from one sheet "live_position" into another sheet "closed" always at the end of the list. Then, these lines should be deleted from the original sheet "live_position". I have this code done without using "array" as a normal "line by line" deleting and coping using loop. That works fine apart from that it’s slow. So I wanted to put together code with arrays hoping it would run faster.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the below example. You did not properly define your array and did not iterate across its values. The key here is to reference the cell value location and actual cell value in order to iterate across the range.

```
On Error GoTo ErrHandle:
    Dim Oblast() As Variant
    Dim xlcell As Range, cleanupRng As Range
    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, k As Integer, l As Integer, counter As Integer

    ' DEFINE DIMENSION OF ARRAY
    ReDim Oblast(0 To Range("A2", Range("A1").End(xlDown)).Count)

    ' INSERT VALUES (CELL LOCATION) IN ARRAY
    i = 0
    For Each xlcell In Range("A2", Range("A1").End(xlDown))
        Oblast(i) = xlcell.Address(False, False, xlA1)
        i = i + 1
    Next xlcell

    j = Worksheets("closed").Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row + 1

    ' ITERATE ACROSS ARRAY
    For k = LBound(Oblast) To UBound(Oblast) - 1
        If Range(Oblast(k)) = 1 Then
            Range(Oblast(k)).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("closed").Range("A" & j)
            Range(Oblast(k)).EntireRow.ClearContents
        End If
    j = j + 1
    Next k

    ' DELETING CLEARED ROWS
    Set cleanupRng = Range("A1:A" & ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count)

    l = 1
    For counter = 1 To ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
        If Len(cleanupRng.Cells(l)) = 0 Then
            cleanupRng.Cells(l).EntireRow.Delete
        Else
            l = l + 1
        End If
    Next counter
    Exit Sub

ErrHandle:
    MsgBox Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description
    Exit Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Parfait! looks good. I am getting debug here"If Range(Oblast(k)) = 1 Then".Cannot fix it :(. Regarding "ClearContents" this is not exactly what I am looking for. I need to remove those lines. I thought  when using array I dont need to insist on looping from the bottom as I had to when looping through range. This should be one of the advantage when using arrays.

Comment: Instead of `ClearContents` use `.Delete`

Comment: And no, there is no such advantage: whenever you are removing items from a collection, you have to step backwards. In this case, you're probably better off just using the worksheet/range objects, instead of using an array -- you're actually creating extra work by using an array as an intermediary step.

Comment: @Ludek, see my edited code. The upper limit of the array had to be one less since arrays begin at the 0 element. I also added a clean up that deletes the rows just cleared, best done in another loop. Finally I add error handling. As for your last item, forgive me but I do not know any programming language that does not specify beginning to end point of its array, list, etc. if requiring a return of all its contents.

Comment: @David, I agree. Initially, I was going to respond that using arrays for this is an overworked solution and simply referencing a range is optimal but the OP wanted to learn about VBA arrays.

Comment: Of course! @Parfait my comment was a reply to OP, and not a criticism of your answer. Cheers :)

Comment: Guys thanks a lot! I have this kind of code running with range object but it runs slowly so I thought this array might speed it up. Am I wrong again?